# Error: Failed to load plugin schemas | Azure | Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

│ Error: Failed to load plugin schemas
│
│ Error while loading schemas for plugin components: Failed to obtain provider schema: Could not load the schema for
│ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm: failed to instantiate provider
│ "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm" to obtain schema: fork/exec
│ .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm/3.10.0/windows_386/terraform-provider-azurerm_v3.10.0_x5.exe:
│ The parameter is incorrect...[image]

Comment: This is a 32-bit machine?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receving due to you already have lockfile for specific version and now you are trying to intatite with another version and do terraform plan.

Resoulation : Delete your `.terraform.lock.hcl` file and (`.tfstate` file if created) then again do `terraform init` to intialize the update version of terraform.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.3.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
    features{}
}
```

Comment: I did that part also but nothing is working at all. Is there any another way? When I ran init first it was a blank folder only with my main.tf code.

Comment: did you change your azurerm version after terraform init ?

Comment: No!! Rahul , I didn't

Comment: Lets have a discussion : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245870/terraformdiscussion