# "Could not load the schema for provider" Both AWS and AzureRM after init

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure

I have a terraform project that I'm working on that I wanted to do automated testing against.

Locally, the testing framework works fine but it's failing on my build/test server.

I have checked and order of events on the server are:

1. Check if the terraform folder and lock file exist, they don't
2. Run terraform init on 'default' workspace
3. Check if the terraform folder and lock file exist, they do
4. Swap terraform workspaces to my intended workspace and run init again
5. Build a custom tfvars file
6. Run apply on the workspace with the var file

The error I'm getting is:

```
[31mâ•·[0m[0m
[31mâ”‚[0m [0m[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mFailed to load plugin schemas[0m
[31mâ”‚[0m [0m
[31mâ”‚[0m [0m[0mError while loading schemas for plugin components: 2 problems:
[31mâ”‚[0m [0m
[31mâ”‚[0m [0m- Failed to obtain provider schema: Could not load the schema for provider
[31mâ”‚[0m [0mregistry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws: failed to instantiate provider
[31mâ”‚[0m [0m"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" to obtain schema: Unrecognized remote
[31mâ”‚[0m [0mplugin message: 
[31mâ”‚[0m [0m
[31mâ”‚[0m [0mThis usually means that the plugin is either invalid or simply
[31mâ”‚[0m [0mneeds to be recompiled to support the latest protocol..
[31mâ”‚[0m [0m- Failed to obtain provider schema: Could not load the schema for provider
[31mâ”‚[0m [0mregistry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm: failed to instantiate provider
[31mâ”‚[0m [0m"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm" to obtain schema: Unrecognized
[31mâ”‚[0m [0mremote plugin message: 
[31mâ”‚[0m [0m
[31mâ”‚[0m [0mThis usually means that the plugin is either invalid or simply
[31mâ”‚[0m [0mneeds to be recompiled to support the latest protocol...
[31mâ•µ[0m[0m
```

Both [Error: Failed to load plugin schemas | Azure | Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72709458/error-failed-to-load-plugin-schemas-azure-terraform?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C207.8681) and [Terraform Error: Failed to load plugin schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74540114/terraform-error-failed-to-load-plugin-schemas?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C150.9940)
say to remove the old terraform folder but in this case it doesn't exist prior to the init

I have tried using `-upgrade` and `-reconfigure` in the init as well as check if the terraform files exist prior to the init.

I don't understand why I'm getting this failure during the apply stage.

Comment: Which OS and CPU are you using?

Comment: @MarkoE, Ubuntu and a 64 bit CPU. Why do you ask? I'd like to know more about the issue you're thinking about.

Comment: Sometimes it happens that there isn't a suitable binary (e.g., M1 chip) but I was just wondering if it's an unusual combination.

Comment: It seems like the plugin executables are somehow incompatible with your system and so are failing to start up at all; Terraform is noticing that they aren't correctly speaking the plugin protocol, and so returns an error. I'm not sure why that would be but it might be interesting to try to directly execute the plugin programs from your shell. You can find them under `.terraform/providers` and after all of the nested directories you will find executable files with name prefixes like `terraform-provider-aws`.

Comment: Normally running a provider executable directly prints an error message about them being plugins and not intended for direct execution. I'm wondering if you'll see a different kind of error message which explains why your system isn't able to execute these programs at all.

Comment: (If you try this and learn something interesting, please edit your question to include the exact error messages you saw.)

Comment: @MartinAtkins, 
`
This binary is a plugin. These are not meant to be executed directly.
Please execute the program that consumes these plugins, which will
load any plugins automatically
`

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately that result suggests that the executables _are_ valid for your system but they are somehow malfunctioning on startup. That makes this considerably harder to debug because they seem to fail only when running in Terraform. 

Comment: The Stack Overflow format unfortunately isn't a great fit for this sort of ongoing debugging conversation. It might work out better to discuss this in [the official Terraform community forum](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/c/terraform-core/27), since that forum doesn't have the same rigid Q&A format as Stack Overflow. I participate over there and so could suggest some other debugging strategies to try. If we find a good answer I'd be happy to share a version of it back over here afterwards for anyone who might find your question in future.

Comment: @MartinAtkins, I've created one here: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/could-not-load-the-schema-for-provider-for-both-aws-and-azurerm-after-init/48030